# Use static dictionary in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I use SignalR in my asp.net web application. Session state doesn't exist in SignalR hub, so I decided to save `username <-> connectionId` pair in static dictionary.

```
public static class UsernameConnectionsMaps
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static void Add(string username, string connectionId)
    {
       data[username] = connectionId;
    } 

    public static string Get(string username)
    {
       return data[username];
    }

    public static void Remove(string username)
    {
       return data.Remove(username);
    }  
}
```

On a particular controller request, I want to send data to the client with signalR. Knowing the username of current user, I can easily get connectionId for the client and send data.

I use `Get` method in my controller.
I use `Add` and `Remove` methods in hub's `OnConnected()` and `OnDisconnected()` methods respectively.

I am interested in, if this solution will have any problem regarding thread safety (or other) in my web application? What will be better approach?

Comment: I assume that any given point only one session will be for one user

Comment: The major issue I can think of is if the application pool is recycled (which usually happens automatically in IIS periodically) then you'll lose your list of connections from memory, which clearly will cause you problems. It'd be better to persist this somewhere like a database, IMHO

Comment: If you are going to use a dictionary, you should use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) for thread safety. That being said, it is more common to store a session identifier in a cookie, using either a cryptographically random identifier or some form of encryption or tamper-resistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a static dictionary you will lose the ability to [scale out](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/scaling-up-and-scaling-out-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) your API. 
Each instance will keep a different static Dictionary, so notifications will not always reach their destination, consider [azure signalr](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/) or some kind of persistent storage like redis.

Comment: There is no plan to scale this application, but in case of it, it is good point

Comment: Even if you do not intend to scale out, you will lose the data if the app pool recycles.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do and it is what is said in the Microsoft documentation, map users to groups, even if it will produce groups with single users or a groups with many users that are actually the same user. Even if you will use `Redis backplane` or `Azure SignalR`, you will have the groups in all context and can communicate with them, add, remove and etc...

> A single user can have multiple connections to a SignalR app. For example, a user could be connected on their desktop as well as their phone. Each device has a separate SignalR connection, but they're all associated with the same user. If a message is sent to the user, all of the connections associated with that user receive the message.